# Best way to store json object from rest api in an offline cordova app

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I'm building an AngularJS application wrapped with Cordova for Android and iOS.
All my datas come from my rest API.

I have urls like `my.api/groups/1/items` to get the list of items

```
 [
    {
        id: 5,
        type: "foo",
        title: "Item 5",
        group: 1,
        body: "<p>Some content</p> ",
        img: "http://my.website/images/item5.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        ...
    }
]
```

and `my.api/items/5` to get a specific item

```
{
    id: 5,
    type: "foo",
    title: "Item 5",
    group: 1,
    body: "<p>Some content</p> ",
    img: "http://my.website/images/item5.jpg"
}
```

I retrieve my datas with restangular and it works perfectly

```
Restangular.one('group', id).getList('items').then(function(data){
  $scope.items = data;
});
```

Now I want that datas be available offline and refreshed time to time.
Localstorage is not possible because I ll have +5MB of datas and images.

- I see a lot of posts about file API but does it mean I need to have a file for each item?
  eg: item1.json, item2.json and a file for the list items.json
  I think there is a better solution than having 500+ different files...
- How to handle images? Do I need to parse my api, download images and replace with local links?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use WebSQL? As a web standard, it is dead, but it works well on mobile and works great in PhoneGap/Cordova. As for images, I'd probably store them as binary though on the file system.